# Random optimization problem

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, probability-distributions, combinatorial-optimization, sampling

Let $V$ be a set of $n$-dimensional vectors such that, for each ${\bf v}\in V$ and for each index $i\in [n-1]$, we have $0\le v_{i+1}\le v_i$. Let $P(\cdot)$ be a discrete probability distribution over $V$.

We are given the expected number $\mu$ of positive (i.e. non-null) vector components of a vector selected from $V$ with $P(\cdot)$.

---

**Question**: What is the *maximum* value of $\alpha$ for which the following inequality always holds? 
$$\max_{{\bf u}\in V} \sum_{i=1}^{\lceil \mu \rceil} u_i \ge \alpha\,\mathbb{E}_{P({\bf v})} ||{\bf v}||_1$$

(Does it always hold even for $\alpha=1$?)

Comment: You mean the *maximum* value of $\alpha$?

Comment: As @IosifPinelis mentioned, a minimal $\alpha$ doesn't make that much sense here. For the maximal one, you can easily construct an example that breaks for all $\alpha > 1$, e.g. by having only a single vector in $V$.

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inequality holds with $\alpha=1/2$. Indeed, let $U=(U_1,\dots,U_n)$ be a random vector in $V$ with $N$ non-null coordinates, so that $U_1\ge\dots\ge U_N>0=U_{N+1}=\dots=U_n$; here $N$ is also random. Let $\nu:=\lceil \mu \rceil$. Let 
$$M:=\max_{{\bf u}\in V} \sum_{i=1}^\nu u_i. 
$$
Then 
$$M\ge \sum_{i=1}^\nu U_i\ge\Big(1\wedge\frac\nu N\Big)\sum_{i=1}^N U_i
=\Big(1\wedge\frac\nu N\Big)\sum_{i=1}^n U_i.
$$
So,
$$\|U\|_1=\sum_{i=1}^n U_i\le\Big(1\vee\frac N\nu\Big)M\le\Big(1+\frac N\nu\Big)M
$$
and hence 
$$E\|U\|_1\le\Big(1+\frac{EN}\nu\Big)M=\Big(1+\frac{\mu}\nu\Big)M\le2M,
$$
so that 
$$M\ge\tfrac12\,E\|U\|_1,$$
as claimed.

Comment: Thank you losif Pinelis!